# Laplace transform of right/left derivative?

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-transform, laplace-transform

Assume the derivative of a function $f$ does not exist everywhere, let's say that it exists everywhere except on a countable set, and that it is continuous between each two successive points of this contountable set. Assume also that the laplace transform of $f$ exists.

Can we still define the Laplace transform of the "almost everywhere" derivative of $f$ ? And in this situation, can we define a Laplace transform for the right/left derivative of $f$ ?  If yes, what is the expression of such transform ?

Comment: The value of the integral of a function is not impacted by the value of the function on a set of measure $0$.

Comment: I agree with that, but what would be the expression of $\mathcal{L}(f')$ in this case ? In the proof of Laplace transform of derivative, they use integration by parts to obtain $sF(s)-f(0)$. Here $f$ is just continuous and differentiable almost everywhere, so it is not even absolutely continuous in general, and therefore integration by parts does not hold ?

Comment: You're asking whether the LT of a function $f$ exists if $f'$ exists a.e., correct?  And $f$ is a "nice function" (What does "nice"mean?) with piecewise continuous derivative.  The function $e^{t^2}$ is $C^\infty$, but has no LT.  $f$ needs to be of exponential order for the LT to exist in some region of the complex $s$-palne.

Comment: Oh sorry, it was my mistake. I did not want $f'$ to be piecewise continuous, but only to exist everywhere except on a countable set, and to be continuous between each two points of this set. I guess that this is not sufficient for the existence of LT right ?

Comment: I've edited my question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $t_n$, $1\le n\le N$ be the points of discontinuity of $f'$.  Then, we have for $t_1\ne 0$

$$\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}\{f'\}(s)&=\int_0^{t_1}f'(t)e^{-st}\,dt+\sum_{n=1}^{N-1} \int_{t_n}^{t_{n+1}}f'(t)e^{-st}\,dt+\int_{t_{N}}^\infty f'(t)e^{-st}\,dt\\\\
&=s\int_0^\infty f(t) e^{-st}\,dt-f(0^+)-\sum_{n=1}^{N}(f(t_n^+)-f(t_n^-)) e^{-st_n}
\end{align}$$